# I am asserting a variable in Mathematica as Real yet it is not implementing it!

Tags: matrix, symbolic, assumptions, assignment

```
Element[\[Theta], Reals]; 
    Ga = g; 
    Gb = g*Exp[I*\[Theta]]; 
    {{Conjugate[Gb], Ga}, {Ga, Gb}}
```

I have a code as such for a matrix as given above. as output I get this

```
{{Conjugate[g]/E^(I*Conjugate[\[Theta]]), g}, {g, E^(I*\[Theta])*g}}
```

\Theta is still output as Conjugate[[Theta]],even when it was asserted as Reals.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Assumptions = Element[\[Theta], Reals];
Ga = g;
Gb = g*Exp[I*\[Theta]];
{{Conjugate[Gb], Ga}, {Ga, Gb}} // Simplify

(*{{E^(-I \[Theta]) Conjugate[g], g}, {g, g E^(I \[Theta])}}*)
```